# Java controller getting only first item from Set via JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

Trying to save One to Many JPA relationship. I have written a custom controller. I am getting only the first id in giftSet and not all the ids. I have simplified the code.

My Post request-

```
{
  "name": "Project 7",
  "giftSet": [
    {
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "id":"33"
    }
  ]
}

class Holiday{
  private String name;
  private Set<GiftConfig> giftSets;
}

class GiftSet {
  private Integer id;
  private Holiday holiday;
}

class GiftConfig {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/api/saveholiday")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Holiday>> saveHoliday(@RequestBody Holiday holiday) {
  System.out.println(holiday);
  return null;
}
```

First, I add multiple GiftConfig. After that, while creating Holiday, I add details for GiftSet as well.

In debug mode, I see only id 1 in giftSet and not both ids 1 and 33.
Note- Changing Set to List is not an option.

Comment: Can you post full `GiftSet` class? Is there an `equals()/hashCode()` implementation?

Comment: There is no equals()/hashCode() implementation. I am using Lombok for Getters and Setters.

Comment: I updated the code. I'm extremely sorry, I forgot to add one class.

Comment: if you are using Lombok, is the `GiftSet` class annotated with any Lombok annotation?

Comment: @Kedar If you are using lambok you need to include your lambok annotations. E.g. `@Data`, or `@Setters`, `@Getters`. In my answer I did include them and things were working. Happy new year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Introduction

I see 2 problems and one possible last issue.

1. You are missing setters/getters in order for de-serialization to work on the JSON.
2. Your payload doesn't seem to be working for me.

As pcoates mentioned in a comment, you could also use `@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)` - but I haven't tested this.

Finally, also be careful about having a circular reference if you convert from java back to JSON. I see that a Holiday has a set of giftSets, but a giftSet points to a holiday. 
If the gitset points to the same parent holiday, this is a circular reference and will crash.

### Getters and Setters

Your problem is that you are missing getters and setters.
Either use lombok and add a @data annotation or add a getter and setter .

```
@Data
    public  static class Holiday{
        private String name;
        private Set<GiftSet> giftSets;
    }

    @Data
    public static class  GiftSet {
        private Integer id;
        private Holiday holiday;
    }
```

### Payload

I used the following payload:

```
{
  "name": "HolidaySet",
  "giftSets": [
    {
      "id": 1111,
      "holiday": {
        "name": null,
        "giftSets": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 1112,
      "holiday": {
        "name": null,
        "giftSets": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

### Quick Test

I did a quick test to see what the payload should be like.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/api/saveholiday")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Holiday>> saveHoliday(@RequestBody Holiday holiday) throws JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println(holiday);

        fakeItTest();

        return null;
    }

    private void fakeItTest() throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Set<GiftSet> giftSets2 = new HashSet<>();
        GiftSet gg = new GiftSet();
        gg.setId(1111);
        gg.setHoliday(new Holiday());
        giftSets2.add(gg);

        GiftSet gg2 = new GiftSet();
        gg2.setId(1112);
        gg2.setHoliday(new Holiday());
        giftSets2.add(gg2);

        Holiday holiday2 = new Holiday();
        holiday2.setName("HolidaySet");
        holiday2.setGiftSets(giftSets2);

        String a = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(holiday2);
        System.out.println(a);
    }


    @Data
    public  static class Holiday{
        private String name;
        private Set<GiftSet> giftSets;
    }

    @Data
    public static class  GiftSet {
        private Integer id;
        private Holiday holiday;
    }
```

Comment: Setters and getters aren't mandatory. You can configure Jackson to use fields. e.g. use @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY) on the class. Can also be done globally.

Comment: @pcoates yes that's true. It's not that commonly used though AFAK.

Comment: I am already using Lombok, hence, no getters and setters. Where do you think I'm going wrong?

Comment: I updated the code. I'm extremely sorry, I forgot to add one class.

Comment: @Kedar my solution will work, you just need to change giftSet to giftConfig in some of the <> . One problem I see is you are missing the `@Data` lambok annotation.